# ValueError: substring not found

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror

I tried to check if `lower[lower.index(j)+shift]>26`, but it returned

> ValueError: substring not found in lower.index(j)+shift>26

My code:

```
def build_shift_dict(self, shift):
    lower=string.ascii_lowercase
    upper=string.ascii_uppercase
    d={}
    for j in self.message_text:
        if lower.index(j)+shift>26: # or if lower[lower.index(j)+shift]>26:
            print('something')
        if j.islower():
            d[j]=lower[lower.index(j)+shift]
        else:
            d[j]=upper[upper.index(j)+shift]
    return d
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterable.index(obj) method will raise a Value error if the 'obj' is not found in the iterable.

So something in `self.message_text` is not part of `string.ascii_lowercase`.

Try wrapping the line in a try-except clause.

```
try:
    lower.index(j)
except ValueError:
    print('{} not found in the search space.'format(j))
    continue
```

Comment: oh, thank you i understood my problem. i just had to write if lower.index(j)+shift>26 in if j.islower()